# datatables only show sorting arrow on the sorted column

Tags: jquery, datatables

In Jquery DataTables, I have a table that successfully sorts on column clicking.  What I want to have happen is to only see one sort arrow for the entire th row.  That arrow would be an up or down arrow on the clicked column.  By default, however, I see up and down arrows on every column header.  Here is my current call:

```
$('#results-table').dataTable( {
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "aoColumns": [{"bSortable":false}, null]
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each sortable column has `class="sorting"` on it, coming from the jquery.dataTables.css file. This class sets the background to contain the arrows:

```
.sorting {
    background: url("../images/sort_both.png") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
}
```

You could manually modify this file to your liking (or by overriding it in a separate location):

```
.sorting {
}
```

Comment: you would want to make a new class that overwrites background with nothing, then apply it to the columns you don't want arrows on.